# MVC 5 Custom Validation Validate Before Next Tab

Tags: c#, validation, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I would like the custom validation to fire before going next Tab or prevent on going to next Tab if custom validation does not meet the requirement like the other fields [image]

Model

```
[EnsureMinimumElementsAttributeDropOff(ErrorMessage = "You must supply at least one Drop Off Date")]
public virtual List<DropOffDate> DropOffDates { get; set; }
```

Custom Validation

```
public class EnsureMinimumElementsAttributeDropOff : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var list = value as List<DropOffDate>;

        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                // check if at least 1 row is filled for Drop-off Date by user
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Date) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.StartTime)
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.EndTime))
                    return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Custom Validation Works but it only validate after the page is Submit/Post. 
 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, have you tried the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add client side validation to it.

This will carry out validation in the browser before it submits to the server, preventing posts when the form is invalid.

Guides:

http://www.itorian.com/2013/08/enabling-client-side-validation-on.html?m=1

http://blog.andrei.rinea.ro/2013/06/28/building-client-javascript-custom-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-4-using-jquery/

https://hossamhassan47.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/mvc-4-0-how-to-support-client-side-custom-validation/

To trigger validation when you change tabs call valid()

```
if(!$("#form_id").valid())
        // keep on same tab
```

This will validate the form and return its state, based on that you can allow/disallow them to change tabs and address the issues.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted, its exactly what is needed

Comment: [Are link-only answers poor practice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice), [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: Reduces repetition, plus helps bloggers increase their profiles

Comment: Read the links, please.